# Unable to access URLs other than googleapis.com from Firebase emulator using fetch()

Tags: firebase, fetch, emulation

I'm trying to create some Firebase Cloud Functions and test them locally using

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

These functions supposed to call some external services using fetch.

I find that I can call these external services when the functions are deployed to the Firebase cloud, but cannot invoke them when running locally in the emulator:

```
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';

export const fetchTest = functions
    .region(config.firebaseRegion)
    .https.onRequest((request: Request, response: Response) => {
        fetch("https://www.wikipedia.org/", {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(value => {
            console.log("Fetched: ", value);
        }).catch(reason => {
            console.log("Fetch failed: ", reason);
        });

        fetch("https://googleapis.com/foo", {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(value => {
            console.log("Fetched: ", value);
        }).catch(reason => {
            console.log("Fetch failed: ", reason);
        });
        response.send("Done");
    });
```

This is the output I get when invoking fetchTest in the emulator:

```
⚠  Unknown network resource requested!
   - URL: "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://googleapis.com/foo"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
```

Looking at the source code there seems to be some filtering implemented in the emulator:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/0586ee1e23adc64b0fe8607a026ba472a6bd7d2e/src/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.ts

```
  if (href && !history[href]) {
    history[href] = true;
    if (href.indexOf("googleapis.com") !== -1) {
      new EmulatorLog("SYSTEM", "googleapis-network-access", "", {
        href,
        module: bundle.name,
      }).log();
    } else {
      new EmulatorLog("SYSTEM", "unidentified-network-access", "", {
        href,
        module: bundle.name,
      }).log();
    }
  }
```

Are there any reason for such restrictions? And is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have questions about how the emulator works, you should post an issue on GitHub rather than Stack Overflow. Issues there will definitely be seen by Firebase engineers.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1503

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you see "Unknown network requested" logs like this one:

```
⚠  Unknown network resource requested!
   - URL: "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
```

They are just warnings.  The actual request is allowed through.  The log is meant to tell you that the emulators are accessing resources outside your machine. This is normally something people want to avoid because local testing is meant to be hermetic, but sometimes it's what you want to do and you can ignore the warnings safely!